# How to implement Single Responsiblity Principle with RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, microservices

I have a couple of microservices:

- WebClient, which sends data from UI to other services
- Service One, which can do some stuff with data from WebClient AND RETURNS IT back to WebClient
- Service Two, which can SAVE data from WebClient to the Database and DOES NOT return anything to WebClient

And in WebClient I have a class called MessageBusClient (works with RabbitMQ). Should I send all my requests to a various services from this ONE class, or should I split this client to multiple classes (like, for example MessageBusServiceOneClient, MessageBusServiceTwoClient), and that way separate that logic and not have a spaghetti code?

Comment: That entirly depends on how you intend to use that messagebus-client. How does using it differes between calls to Service One and Service Two?  If these calls are equal, I don't see any point in having two different messagebus-clients. But without any code it's üretty hard to give you further suggestions. Please provide some codew that demonstrates your structure and how you intend to use the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Having a class responsible for sending messages is fairly normal, and would be considered a "single thing". But it should probably be able to handle any arbitrary messages. If it need to handle messages for Service One and Service Two differently somehow, you might want to consider making two separate versions.

Another way to think about it is infrastructure logic and business logic. Shuffling messages around is infrastructure. Processing messages is business logic. Ofc, a good architecture is much more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

Your client should contain the common logic to be able to integrate with RabbitMQ. You shouldn't have this logic duplicated in multiple places. However as you've noticed you'll quickly get a very bloated client if you introduce a new method for message type and queue you want to publish to.

So your services which are calling the client should build a message to be put on a queue, then send this to the client. The client can be configured with a mapping between message type and the queue(s) that it should be sent to. Then it'll perform the general logic to add the message to the configured queue.